# How to prevent wordpress multisite to generate queries for each blog?

Tags: wordpress

I have a multisite installation and I have a performance issues, because there is too much queries. When I inspect the queries, I see that there is a queries for each blog. It doesn`t metter what I am loading.

```
[141] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT * FROM wp_blogs WHERE blog_id = 61 /* get_blog_details */
        [1] => 0.0010240077972412
        [2] => require('path-to-root\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('path-to-root\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, _wp_admin_bar_init, WP_Admin_Bar->initialize, get_blogs_of_user, get_blog_details
    )

[142] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_61_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'
        [1] => 0.0028109550476074
        [2] => require('path-to-root\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('path-to-root\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, _wp_admin_bar_init, WP_Admin_Bar->initialize, get_blogs_of_user, get_blog_details, switch_to_blog, WP_Roles->reinit, get_option, wp_load_alloptions
    )
```

There is a queries for each blog.

Do you have an idea how to stop them?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, but it loads options, which is pretty normal. Use persistent caching like Memcached - those queries will never hit the database.

Comment: And, by the way, most of those  queries are run only if you are a logged in  super admin. Try anylizing queries when you are logged out.

Comment: This is a long time after your question, but I've run into the same problem. In addition to the toolbar, which you can overwrite or disable, it also occurs in admin_header.php, in the `wp_user_settings()` call. However, there doesn't seem to be a way around that other than just making your user an admin of less sites. Did you ever find a fix for this?